# SPListItem: get associated eml file

Tags: 2010, splistitem, discussion-board

I have a discussion board set up with an email drop folder. Once an .eml file is copied into the drop folder, it would disappear and the new discussion/message would be added to my discussion board. Now my question is - is it possible to retrieve the original .eml file programmatically through the SPListItem instance? Any other way?

Thank you in advance.